# Function is returning garbage value

Tags: c, function

I have the following code in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Global variables :
int i; 
int x[10]; 
int Nmax;
int sum; 

// Functions used :
void Summation();
int Average(float avg); // This function will return avg

int main()
{
    float avg;

    printf("Mention how many numbers to be added\n");
    scanf("%d",&Nmax);
    printf("Enter %d numbers\n",Nmax);
    for (i=0; i<Nmax; i++){
      scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }

    Summation();

    Average(avg); 

    printf("%d %d %f\n",Nmax,sum,avg);
    printf("Average = %.2f\n",avg);
    return 0;
}

// Summation :
void Summation()
{
    sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<Nmax; i++) {
        sum=sum+x[i];
    }
    printf("Sum of them = %d\n",sum);
}


// Average
int Average(float avg)
{ 
    avg=(float)sum/(float)Nmax;
    return avg;
}
```

Somehow the function `Average` is not returning the expected average value. 
Instead it's showing a garbage value.

A typical input/output :

```
Mention how many numbers to be added
4
Enter 4 numbers
1 2 3 4
Sum of them = 10
4 10 1637156136366093893632.000000
Average = 1637156136366093893632.00
```

What's going wrong here? Hope I don't require a pointer here or do I?

Comment: Please write your code so humans can understand, also don't use global variables if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Your `Average` function doesn't have sum or NMax as an input parameter.

Comment: @rghome It doesn't need them as they are global variables.

Comment: @CoolGuy Exactly, the first source of problems in many cases.

Comment: So why are you passing avg as a parameter? In fact, why have a function at all? There is no point.

Comment: @rghome Yes. Agreed. OP's code isn't good.

Comment: @rghome Perhaps the `Average()` function was requested in the homework.

Comment: I am not sure whether you got the purpose of the code correctly. The code was meant to demonstrate how a fortran subroutine could be translated into a C function routine. In standard fortran we generally return the result to main through an argument. In teaching, we need to compare with other languages often, but stackoverflow maybe meant for smart codes only and hence negative vote. If you recommend, I can try to edit the title/text elaborating the purpose.

Comment: Take in all the points raised so far and clean up that mess of globals and int/float.  If you still have a problem, either append new code version to this question, or ask another question.

Comment: If you want to return a value through a parameter, you need to pass a pointer in. I take your point that you are learning, but the idea of stackoverflow is more to share answers to common problems rather fixing-up badly written code. If every single programmer learning to code posted their own question every time they made a mistake, the site would sink without a trace.

Comment: @rghome "the site would sink without a trace" may not happen because people mark with duplicates often and posts get deleted too. But one *naive* post prevents others from posting similar stuff again.  I'm happy to welcome your suggestions, I can try to delete mine if you insist.

Comment: The trouble is that questions like this are not strictly duplicates of anything since it is down to an individual programming error. Anyway, it is not a big deal. Leave it or delete is as you wish.

Comment: "Translating" an ancient language like Fortran to a more modern language with strong support for local variables and functions like C often results in Spaghetti code. It is almost always a bad idea. Better re-implement or port the problem, not just each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the average function you are passing the argument as pass by value. Once you call the function your are not assigning the return value back to the avg variable inside the main function. So what you are printing is the garbage value inside the avg variable declared in main function. Change your code to

```
avg = Average(avg);
```

Also this is a very bad way of writing c programs. Please dont you use global variables if you dont need them.

Comment: Thanks, you're a bit kind to get me correct. OK, I thought `avg` argument could get passed to the main, but doesn't happen in C (unlike Fortran). I think, I could use `avg=Average()` as well and `return avg` inside the function `Average()`. However, I'm stilling getting a wrong value ! `avg=2.0` instead of 2.5 !

Comment: thats because your function has return type int. So its only returning an int value and not a float. change your function to 'float Average'

Comment: Oops! I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are mixing `int` and `float` and that can cause problems.
2. You are never initializing `avg` in `main()`, use parameters instead of global variables to avoid the confusion. You pass `avg`'s value to `Average()` it has absolutely no use in this case.

   In [c](/questions/tagged/c) parameters to functions are always passed by value so the value of `avg` is not being modified in `Average()`, you may think it is because you seem confused about how you can modify global variables everywhere. The truth is *global variables* are mean, of course they have their uses for example, a global state in a library could be stored in a global variable<sup>1</sup> but generally they are not needed.

Try like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Functions used :
float Summation(float *data, int size);
float Average(float *data, int size); // This function will return avg

int 
main(void)
{
    int size;

    printf("Mention how many numbers to be added\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) == 1)
    {
        float data[size];
        float sum;
        float average;
        int i;

        printf("Enter %d numbers\n", size);
        for (i = 0 ; ((i < size) && (scanf("%f", &data[i]) == 1)) ; i++)
            ;
        size = i;
        sum = Summation(data, size);
        average = Average(data, size);

        printf("%d %f %f\n", size, sum, average);
        printf("Average = %.2f\n", average);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Summation :
float
Summation(float *data, int size)
{
    float sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        sum = sum + data[i];
    return sum;
}


// Average
float
Average(float *data, int size)
{
    return Summation(data, size) / (float) size;
}
```

Note that you "*don't really need an `Average()` function.*", although it could be useful to make the API clean.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Although I don't like that either, it makes the library very limited in multithreaded environments. Still sometimes it makes senes, but you can always have a structure with all the needed data and pass it in every call to the library API. So global variables are very rarely good.</sub>